# Pandas data transformation question, rows as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following data as a python pandas dataframe,

```
Date         metric    value
01/01/2019   XYZ       100
02/01/2019   XYZ       98
03/01/2019   XYZ       102
04/01/2019   XYZ       95
05/01/2019   XYZ       104
06/01/2019   XYZ       105
.
.
.
12/08/2019   XYZ       123(or some value)
```

I would like to transform it as below,

```
Date        metric   v1   v2   v3   v4   v5  v6  v7
01/01/2019   XYZ     100  98   102  95  104 104 105
02/01/2019   XYZ     98   102  95   104 104 105 105
.
.
.
```

For each day, take previous **n** days data from value column, in the above example n is 7.So,

```
v1- current days value
v2- previous day value(current day - 1 day's) value
v3- (current day - 2 day's) value
.
.
so on
```

I could have done the following,

```
df["v1"] = df["value"]
df["v2"] = df.shift(periods=-1)["value"]
df["v3"] = df.shift(periods=-2)["value"]
df["v4"] = df.shift(periods=-3)["value"]
.
.
```

I am looking for a more elegant way, if any, other than using `df.shift` . If the **n** is huge number then i need to have those many columns shifted as mentioned above which i would like to avoid.

Comment: It seems that you shifted the data forwards...

Comment: @Novak Thanks for pointing :) I have corrected it to backward shift

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get values of the column as a list and load it to numpy array. Then in a loop, rotate an array for 1 in some direction and assign it to the df column. Then repeat that for each of the columns.

```
import numpy

df["v1"] = df["value"]
arr = np.arr(df.['value'].values)
for i in ['v2', 'v3' .. , 'vn']:
    arr = np.roll(arr, 1)
    df[i] = arr
```

Comment: This works for the most part, with the np.roll the values from latest dates rotated which i would like to avoid.
`10/08/2019   XYZ     118   121  123   NA NA NA NA
 11/08/2019   XYZ      121   123  NA   NA NA  NA  NA
 12/08/2019   XYZ      123   NA   NA   NA  NA NA  NA`
I am fine with NA in the last 7 days of data, I would discard them. Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: You can just use `fillna` from pandas DataFrame I guess... But I still think you have the wrong direction in shifting in your examples. 02/01/2019 is after 01/01/2019. You say that v2 is previous day value. Shouldn't there be 100 in 02/01/2019 v2 position?